# Change desktop background to another default installation background

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, desktop-customization

It is easy to change the background in Windows 8.1, but in *Configuration panel - Desktop Backgrounds*, I cannot choose those backgrounds that are available upon installation of Windows 8. I can choose any background I want, but I cannot find those from installation presets.

Where are these background images stored? Or maybe they aren't installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wallpapers used for the Desktop themes & the Lock screen in Windows 8 or 8.1 are located in: `C:\Windows\Web`

There you will find several subfolders, each with its own set of wallpapers. If you want to know which pictures are in which subfolder, read this article that explains everything: [Where the Desktop & Lock Screen Wallpapers are Stored in Windows 8](http://www.7tutorials.com/where-desktop-lock-screen-wallpapers-are-stored-windows-8).

Comment: In my installation in the folder `C:\Windows\Web\Windows` there is only one image. That means that the other 19 from the installation DVD don't make their way into a final installation...

Comment: Yup, that's correct.